# Where's the Treasure Yeti event?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

I just finished the Modern Day level and the Treasure Yeti no longer appears in the game. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: The Treasure a Yeti no longer appears in the game after I finished new Modern Day level. Only the Piñata Party recurs daily. I want to know if anyone else is also experiencing this issue with Pvs.Z2 and if anyone knows why.

Answer (score 1):

The Yeti is not gone from the game; he is however much more rare.

The Yeti now appears once every couple weeks. Prior to the Modern Day update, I'd get him once about every 18 hours.

Answer (score -1):

The Treasure Yeti random event will trigger typically once a day in a level you have previously completed.

Research

- [onwithoutthesarcasm.com](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/plants-vs-zombies-2-treasure-yeti-guide/)
- [Wikia page on the treasure yeti](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Treasure_Yeti)

Comment: The Treasure Yeti is gone from the game. It has been three days and the Yeti has not been triggered. Thank you for your response.